# Possible to stop Adobe DreamWeaver from rewriting 'onclick' to 'onClick'?

Tags: rewrite, dreamweaver

I've been giving my dev team grief by checking in HTML edited in DW. It turns out that DW has silently been rewriting all instances of 'onclick' to 'onClick' completely breaking the application in Webkit on us.

I've done some digging on Google and this appears to be a bug that goes back to at least 2004. Supposedly it has nothing to do with your code re-writing settings and what triggers it is opening any document that does not contain a Doctype. Few of ours do, given that we're maintaining a framework that's using all sorts of include and dependency files.

In all my Googling, I haven't found a fix, though. Has anyone come across one short of swearing off Adobe products forever?*

- something, btw, that I'm perfectly fine doing...it's just that given the insane IT lockdown on our work machines, we have very few software choices. For now, It's Notepad++ for me.

Comment: What version of Dreamweaver?

Comment: I can't keep up with the number of SE sites anymore. Feel free to move it to whichever site warrants it. As for version, it's CS5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing a search and replace for all 'onClick' to 'onclick' in dreamweavers configuration folder.  [Here's a person who did it and had some luck](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2005/08/03/fixing-the-onclick-in-dreamweaver/).

An aside I would recommend taking the time to learn [Vim](http://www.vim.org/).  Your output might be lacking slightly for a month but if you use it consistently you will overcome it in no time! (speaking from experience)

Comment: This looks like the solution. Brute force FTW!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check out the DW [code rewriting preferences](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7bdaa.html):

> - Fix Invalidly Nested and Unclosed TagsRewrites overlapping tags. For example, ***text*** is rewritten as ***text***. This option also inserts closing quotation marks and closing brackets if they are missing.
> - Rename Form Items When PastingEnsures you don’t have duplicate names for form objects. This option is enabled by default. 
>     Note: Unlike the other options in this preferences dialog box, this option does not apply when you open a document, only when you copy and paste a form element.
> - Remove Extra Closing TagsDeletes closing tags that have no corresponding opening tag.
> - Warn When Fixing Or Removing TagsDisplays a summary of technically invalid HTML that Dreamweaver attempted to correct. The summary notes the location of the problem (using line and column numbers) so that you can find the correction and ensure that it’s rendering as intended.
> - Never Rewrite Code: In Files With ExtensionsAllows you to prevent Dreamweaver from rewriting code in files with the specified filename extensions. This option is particularly useful for files that contain third-party tags.
> - Encode <, >, &, And " In Attribute Values Using &Ensures that attribute values that you enter or edit using Dreamweaver tools such as the Property inspector contain only legal characters. This option is enabled by default. 
>     Note: This option and the following options do not apply to URLs that you type in Code view. Also, they do not cause existing code already in a file to change.
> - Do Not Encode Special CharactersPrevents Dreamweaver from changing URLs to use only legal characters. This option is enabled by default.
> - Encode Special Characters In URL Using &#Ensures that when you enter or edit URLs using Dreamweaver tools such as the Property inspector, those URLs contain only legal characters.
> - Encode Special Characters In URL Using %Operates the same way as the preceding option, but uses a different method of encoding special characters. This encoding method (using the percent sign) may be more compatible with older browsers, but doesn’t work as well with characters from some languages.

Comment: This is a bug outside of the code rewriting preferences. Which is why it's so infuriating. ;)

Answer (score -1):

So write a script that does the conversion. A simple sed script should work:

sed s/onClick/onclick/g

Comment: -1 DA01 asks if there is a way to stop DreamWeaver from behaving as it is, not *how* to change them all.